# Python AES encryption program is returning Memory Error

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycrypto, encryption-asymmetric

So i am following a tutorial on AES implementation with python. It is an project which demanded to implement aes. Following is the code in Python which works fine on small files , but it i tried it ona 1 gb file and then the following error occured

**File "Desktop\AES\encrypting.py", line 73, in 
    encrypted = f.encrypt(encoded)
  File "\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 52, in encrypt
    return self._encrypt_from_parts(data, current_time, iv)
  File "\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 58, in _encrypt_from_parts
    padded_data = padder.update(data) + padder.finalize()
MemoryError**

```
 from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
##Fernet uses 128 bit AES IN CBC mode.

import base64
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC


##The above mentioned modules are imported to aid us in implimenting
##the AES encryption. AES encryption is asymmetric encryption method
##in which the encrtyption key used to encrypt the data
##is the same for decrypting it.UNLIKE RSA where we have two different keys


##Since we dont want to save keys everytime inside a
##file now we will create a password.Now we can take
##either password as input or
##give it inside a variable

password = input("Enter your password. make sure it is strong enough:  ")
print("\n")
text_file = input("Enter the name of text file you want to encrypt:  ")
print("\n")


salt = b'o\x10\xce\xee\xefGE=\xc4\xfe`\xd6=\xd6\xad\xde5\x0f\xa1\xdf\xa0!\x8e[\xab'
#created using os.urandom(25)

##salts are the additional data that are used to protect the
##data which might be similar fo instance there might be a possibility
##that two users can have same passwords.Thus to safeguard it we
##use salt which works as
##SHA256(salt+password)
##Thus in this way the salted value will be different for both of the
##passwords stored and it will be computationaly difficult for the hacker to
##retrieve the password.

#password = "password" #password should not be easily guessable
password22 = password.encode() #encoding the password 

kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(   #Password-based key Derivation function 2
    algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
    length=32,
    salt=salt,
    iterations=100000,
    backend=default_backend()
)
key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password22))
print('Following is the key generated based on your password \n')
print(key)

##This will create an encryption file for key because it is not possible for everyone to remember long keys
##and because it is very crucial for decryption therefore a file is created which will have the encryption key

file = open('encrypt.enc','wb')
file.write(key)
file.close()

##The text file which will be opened for encryption all the text contained inside of this text file will be encrypted

file = open(text_file ,'rb')

data = file.read()

encoded = data

##
##a new object of Fernet class is being created 
f = Fernet(key)

encrypted = f.encrypt(encoded)
print('\n')
print('The encrypted message is as belows \n\n')
print(encrypted)
print('\n\n')

key2 = input("Would you like to decrypt the encrypted message: y/n")

key2 =input("Enter the name of encryption file (It was created in the same directory where your code was executed under the name of encrypt.enc): ")

file = open('encrypt.enc','r')
key = file.read()
file.close()

f2 = Fernet(key)
print(key)
decrypted = f2.decrypt(encrypted)
print('The decrypted message is as belows \n')
print(decrypted)
k = input("The above message is encoded in byte types would you like to convert it into string : y/n ? ")
if (k == 'y'):
    print(decrypted.decode())
else:
    print("THANKS FOR USING OUR PROGRAM")
```

The plan is to encrypt a hard drive so that it can be only an encrypted file is remained else is removed.It would be very helpful for any suggestions as to how can this function encrypt all the F drive along with it's contents inside of it.Also i am still struggling to understand this code very well so if you could explain it that would be a help as well

Answer (score 0):

Fernet buffers all output before returning to prevent misuse before the data is verified. However, this approach is not suitable for encryption of large files without additional framing.

If you want to encrypt large files `cryptography` currently has no high level API for that, but you can use the [streaming GCM](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.modes.GCM) API. This API lives in `hazmat` because it allows users to misuse it in a variety of ways: you could reuse a `(key, nonce)` pair, you could (easily) start processing data before validating the tag when decrypting, etc.